# Primitive element Theorem without Galois group.

Tags: galois-theory

I want to know if exists a demonstration of the Primitive Element Theorem **without using** the Galois Group of the extension. 
Anyone knows a demonstration without it?

Comment: I maybe forgetting something, but of all the proofs I can remember right now **none** uses any Galois anything: just more or less simple fields extensions theory. You have one example here: https://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH404-PrimElem.pdf , and other here http://planetmath.org/proofofprimitiveelementtheorem

Comment: The Primitive element Theorem is valid for non-Galois extensions, in particular for finite separable extensions, so it is not directly related to Galois groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short proof:

Let $n=[L:K]$.

1. If $K$ is finite, $L$ is too, hence the multiplicative group $L^\times$ is cyclic. If $\alpha$ is a generator of this cyclic group, it is obvious that $L=K(\alpha)$.
2. So suppose $K$ is infinite, and let $\Omega$  be an algebraic closure of $K$. As $L$ is a separable extension of degree $n$, there are $n$ $K$-field homomorphisms from $L$ into $\Omega$, $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$. For all $1\le i<j\le n$, denote: 
   $$ E_{ij}=\{ x\in L\mid \sigma_i(x)=\sigma_j(x)\}$$

Each $E_{ij}$ is a proper $K\!$-subspace of $L$ since $\sigma_i\neq\sigma_j$. Hence, by the avoidance lemma for vector spaces over an infinite field, their union is proper subset of $L$.

Let $\alpha\in L\smallsetminus\bigcup\limits_{\!\!1\le i<j\le n\!\!}E_{ij}$. Its minimal polynomial has the $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ as roots, hence it has degree $\ge n$ and
$$n\le [K(\alpha):K]\le [L:K]=n.$$
Thus $[K(\alpha):K] = [L:K]$ and $L=K(\alpha)$.

Comment: Thanks! From which book is this demonstration?

Comment: It was a proof I was given when I was a student. I think the original proof comes from van der Waerden's *Modern Algebra* (a classic originally published in 1930).